# OpenSSH stop writing to auth.log

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, openssh

Two days ago, by accident, I've typed command that restart ssh server. Since then OpenSSH server (version 6.6.1p1) have stopped logging any activity to /var/log/auth.log.

Does anyone have any idea why that happened? How to resolved issue? 
To clarify: there is enough space on HDD, file is not large (about 15k lines) and it is not divided.

Where can I find error logs from OpenSSH?

Hope you'll can help me out here.

Edit 1:
I have used following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

sshd_config looks like:

```
# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key 
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600 ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
```

Comment: Could you add to your question how you stopped and restarted sshd?

Comment: How does your `sshd_config` look like?